# OnOptionsItemSelected doesn't work on android API 19 (but works on android 24)

Tags: java, android

I have the following code in my activity class

```
public class admin_fab_features_grid extends 
 base_activity_for_admin_home_page implements Parcelable {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity_context = getApplicationContext();

    Intent iIntent= getIntent();
    Bundle b = iIntent.getExtras();

    // display the admin_fab_features_grid that contain the dashboard list of all the admin options
    setContentView(R.layout.admin_fab_features_grid);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 }
```

The base_activity_for_admin_home_page.java has the following code

```
public class base_activity_for_admin_home_page extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(Tag, " Into base activity for parent menu");
    _context = getApplicationContext();

    // display the admin_fab_features_grid that contain the dashboard list of all the admin options
    setContentView(R.layout.admin_fab_features_grid);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_admin_home_page, menu);

    Log.d(Tag, "inflate done");




    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

 switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.actionbar_settings:
            return true;

    }

  }


 }
```

The menu_admin_home_page has the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

 tools:context=".MyActivity">



 <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_settings"
    android:title="@string/actionbar_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
 <!--
    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_dropoff"
        android:title="@string/actionbar_dropoff"
        android:orderInCategory="90"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/actionbar_signin"
        android:title="@string/actionbar_signin"
        android:orderInCategory="85"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
-->
<item android:id="@+id/actionbar_logout"
    android:title="@string/actionbar_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="80"
    app:showAsAction="never" />


</menu>
```

The "Settings" menu is enabled in the Toolbar. I can see ":" in the Toolbar. On a device that has Android API24 I am able to click on it and the OnOptionsItemSelected function is getting called. But the same application on a device that has Android API 19 the OnOptionsItemSelected does not get called. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

change [onOptionsItemSelected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) to this and try

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.actionbar_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arpan. But my issue is this - the OnOptionsItemSelected() code works on Android API24. It just doesn't work in Android API19.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the `showAsAction` attribute to `never`, then these menu items will never show as action views. Try this:

showAsAction = ifRoom|withText

```
switch (item.getItemId()) { 
 case R.id.actionbar_settings: 
     doyouraction();
     return true;

 default:        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
  } }
```

Comment: Thanks Niket. I don't want the menu options to display by default in the toolbar. there is the three dots ":" that I see and the options of the menu open up when you click on them. Also my issue is this -  the OnOptionsItemSelected() code works on Android API24. It just doesn't work in Android API19.

Comment: instead of returning super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) , return true. I think that should work

Comment: case R.id.actionbar_settings: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
 your code in onOptionItemSelected

Comment: its not returning true

Comment: Tried that Niket. But it didn't make any difference. I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it after 4 days of pain.

What occurred is that the CoordinatorLayout overlays the GridView on top of the toolbar and that is why the onOptionsItemSelected icons were not getting called. They're being blocked. Toolbar doesn't overlay on-top of the GridView like an actionbar. Its a view itself. To solve this I removed the CoordinatorLayout add an id to the Toolbar and then add android:layout_below="@id/toolbar".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<!--
// <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
-->
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="fab_features.admin_fab_features_grid">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@id/app_bar_toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget_v7_Toolbar_style"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@id/app_bar_toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget_v7_Toolbar_style"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@id/admin_fab_features_grid"
        style="@style/admin_fab_features_grid_gridview"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_toolbar"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```